# iSight camera doesn't work in uBuntu 16.04

Tags: webcam, macbook-pro, camera

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook Pro retina late 2014. My mac also runs Mac OS X 10.11 but Ubuntu is primary OS.

iSight camera doesn't work in ubuntu which caused me frustrated. I tried with some tutorials but it still doesn't work.

Anybody here know how to make it alive in Ubuntu? I appreciate your help a lots. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly related to the following Ubuntu bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isight-firmware-tools/+bug/1247476

Multiple people with similar Macbook Pro models manufactured in 2014 are reporting the same issue.

There is currently an effort to reverse-engineer the iSight webcam driver to create an open-source version; however, without Apple's cooperation, it's a slow process. The driver project is at https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie and it looks like there is an experimental version available; it looks like the driver is now able to stream video, and the wiki on that site has installation instructions if you'd like to try it out.